# Fail to include file within while loop

Tags: php

So, I have a small script fetching some information from a database.
What it basically needs to do is include a svg generated in 'miescudo.php'.

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.id_facebook, t.*
        FROM user_facebook u
        LEFT JOIN user_team t ON u.id = t.id_user
        WHERE u.id_facebook='100003809660283'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div>'.include('miescudo.php').'</div>';
    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
 Warning: include(miescudo.php?id=1
): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in full-path-goes-here/tusequipos.php on line 56 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'miescudo.php?id=1
```

But yet, when I include the file the same way but outside my while loop it works fine.

I assume that the following is the reason to this error, but I haven't figured out how to fix it:

```
// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
```

Any help and advice is much appriciated.

**Oh, and I don't need any reminders about not using the deprecated mysql_* functions. I am well aware and will update this piece of code accordingly - I promise!**

Comment: Forgot to say, that I have been using the complete path - still no success. The files are located in the same directory as well.

Comment: A little off topic here, but you should use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future

Comment: As stated in my post, I am aware and don't need to be reminded @Musterknabe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a file with a GET-Parameter, since the GET-Parameter won't be noticed. Either you have to read the output over the HTTP-Protocol (if allow_url_fopen is enabled, you can just use file_get_contents()) or you can simply use the variable (maybe you need to declare it as global) if you include the script. And remember to use the absolute filepath.

Answer (score 3):

`include` doesn't understand non-absolute URLs. It does **NOT** do an http request unless the string you're passing in as an argument is a full-blown url, which means including the protocol:

```
include('http://example.com/path/to/script.php'); // does an HTTP request
include('/path/to/script.php'); // local request only
include('http://example.com/script.php?foo=bar'); // does an HTTP request
include('script.php?foo=bar'); // local request only, will look for a "...?foo=bar" file
```

Unless an HTTP request is done, your query parameters are going to be treated as if they're literally part of the filename. So PHP wouldn't look for `script.php` and pass in `foo=bar`. It'll look for a file whose name is literally `script.php?foo=bar`.